# Elements not bound when testing with White framework

Tags: wpf, binding, automation, white-framework

I have a wpf application with a simple window that shows a text in a textbox bound to a property of the ViewModel. When I execute the application I can see the text in the textbox, but when I execute a white based test, I have different results, at random:

- most of the times, it's not bound and the test fails.
- sometimes it's bound (I can see the text in the window raised by white), but white throws an exception when the code wants to get the window.
- sometimes (really few) it works.

The code I'm trying to execute is this:

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.Tests.Wpf.MainWindow"     
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">   
  <Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="22,19,0,0"
             Name="name"
             Text="{Binding Path=CountryName}" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="120" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
namespace Sample.Tests.Wpf
{
  public partial class MainWindow
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      Loaded += delegate { DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel
                                         {
                                           CountryName = "Argentina"
                                         };
                          };
    }
  }
}
```

and the test looks like:

```
var app = Application.Launch("Sample.Tests.Wpf.exe");
var window = app.GetWindow("MainWindow");
Assert.IsNotNull(window);
var textbox = window.Get<TextBox>("name");
Assert.AreEqual("Argentina", textbox.Text);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Loaded event is not fired until the window is about to be rendered.  My guess is that it has something to do with the timing of that event.

Does it work if you just assign the DataContext instead of waiting to respond?

```
namespace Sample.Tests.Wpf
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
         public MainWindow()
         {
              InitializeComponent();
              DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel
                                     {
                                       CountryName = "Argentina"
                                     };
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly, I got the same result :(

Comment: It could still be an issue with the timing of the binding execution. It may wait until the control is rendered. Since the White framework may never reach the render stage, you may wish to Forcibly update the binding target of the text box.    Try adding  BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(textbox, TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();   before doing your assert on the Text Property. This should force the binding to update.

Comment: Finally, it was an error on the application configuration that was thrown when executing from a different path. The thing is, it continued "working", but not doing the binding. Weird.

Thanks for the help!